# Compiled CSS file wouldn't display in my browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am new to laravel homestead. I am using a windows 10 for my learning and able to run npm watch-poll. The app.scss is compiled successfully and the app.css file is updated in the public directory but, it wouldn't display in my browser. I have included the CSS script in my blade template. Only when I restart my machine then the css is displayed. Any one can help please. 
I do appreciate.

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your question

Answer (score -1):

This is how i solved this problem in my own project:

1. delete your link tag containing `href="app.css"`
2. save file
3. paste the link tag again
4. save file

If the above doesn't work, try pressing ctrl+f5 to clear browser cache.
How to disable browser cache on chrome:
https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Comment: I deleted the css link from my blade template saving the file and pasted the link again and saved it but, the compiled css is not updated in my browser. For example, if I change the background-color of my home page from red to green from the app.scss, the app.css in the public directory is updated but the color of my home page stays  still stays red.

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl+f5 to clear the browser cache?

Comment: Thank you, that worked but I still need to clear the browser cache each time I update the app.scss file. Any more suggestion please!

Comment: This is how to disable browser cache on chrome: https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Comment: If the solution works, maybe you can accept my answer? Thank you :)